# Is the alternating series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^n \frac {n^2 - 1}{2n^2 + 3}$ divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, divergent-series

I tried every test for convergence and really came up with nothing. Without answering the problem directly, is it possible to determine the divergence or convergence for this series?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^n \frac {n^2 - 1}{2n^2 + 3}$$

If it can be determined could someone give a little hint as to what direction to take? Thank you!

Comment: The terms do not approach to $0$.

Comment: ... [and thus it diverges.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Limit_of_the_summand)

Comment: @Crostul I know, but that just means the alternating series test cant show convergence. Is that the only way to determine it?

Comment: No, it means much more than that. It means divergence. That the sequence of summands converge to zero is a necessary condition (not sufficient) for convergence of the series.

Comment: A place to start for MathJax formatting is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: @chris360 The point you may be missing here is that in order to find out whether or not a particular series is convergent, you FIRST must find out what the sequence does, more specific, when $n$ goes to infinity, what does the infinite term do? This is always the first and very foremost step, no matter what. The outcome of the limit of the sequence is of very much importance as laid out by DonAntonio. Please read his answer. Good luck!

Comment: @imranfat Okay, it appears I have a misconception, I learned that if the alternating sequence (-1)^n * A, only converges if the limit as n goes to infinity of A approaches zero... That being said in this case it doesn't, it approaches a finite value, all other tests I applied failed, and nowhere does it say that if it approaches a value greater than zero then it is divergent, intuitively that makes sense but analytically I am missing proof. I don't agree with the limit does not exist argument because the same could be said for a similar problem that does converge. So am I correct?

Comment: The alternating series test in this case is conclusive. You're not looking at radii of convergence or whether a ratio is less than or greater than 1, you're looking directly at the terms and seeing that they don't converge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A necessary condition **for any convergent** series is that its terms sequence converges to zero... This *must be true* for **all convergent series** : positive, alternating, whatever.

In your case, we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(n^2-1)}{2n^2+3}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)}{2+\frac3{n^2}}\ldots\text{doesn't exist at all}$$

Comment: +1) Your first sentence should become a bumper sticker on every car :) I couldn't word it with more conviction.

Comment: Okay I have found exactly what you said in a math text! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @chris360 Really? Fiuuu! Was I worried... :)

Answer (score 4):

Let
$$a_n=(-1)^n\frac{n^2-1}{2n^2+3}$$

we have $$\forall n\in \mathbb N^* \;\;
|a_n|=\frac{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}{2+\frac{3}{n^2}}$$

which yields to

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}|a_n|=\frac{1}{2}$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty} a_n \neq 0$$

thus, the series $\sum a_n$ is divergent.